# delaying a command in xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, button, alpha

i'm trying to implement a simple animation messing with a alpha value on a button.  But it goes so fast that you can't see the animation.

```
-(void)Flash: (id)sender {
    UIButton *senderButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    for (float i = 0.8; i > 0.2; i = i - 0.1) {
        senderButton.alpha = i;
    }
    senderButton.alpha = 0.9;
}
```

How can slow down the process for every 0.5 second?

Comment: Do you want to make button flashing constantly ?

Comment: @user1816481: The questions is about iOS and Cocoa Touch, not about the development environment XCode. I've changed the tags accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

To diminish the opacity of the view over a specified duration, toss it in an animation block. You can set the alpha - my personal preference is to adjust layer properties for visual treatments such as this (mainly it's just a matter of consistency in my code base). You can use EITHER approach demonstrated here (don't use both) - the difference would be negligible in a situation such as this. If you modify the layer property, you'll need to import the Quart headers.

```
- (void)flash:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

    NSTimeInterval duration = 1;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                     animations:^{

                         // My preferred approach is to set layer opacity...
                         [[button layer] setOpacity:0.1f];

                         // But you could just as easily set alpha (per your original question)
                         [button setAlpha:0.1f];


                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                         // Returns the button to full opacity on completion.
                         [[button layer] setOpacity:1.0f];

                         // Or alternately, alpha
                         [button setAlpha:1.0f];
                     }];

}
```

Comment: `alpha` can be animated without needing to import Quartz

Comment: @jrturton Yes it can, just a slightly different approach based on my personal preference. I'll edit the answer to demonstrate alpha.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (float i = 0.8; i > 0.2; i = i - 0.1) {
    senderButton.alpha = i;
}
```

You have (at least) two problems here:

1. You're changing `alpha` about six times as fast as the device can do it, which is *really* fast. There's absolutely no way that anyone could see that happen. You need to add a delay between each change to slow things down.
2. You're changing `alpha` a bunch of times without redrawing the view. Redrawing happens as part of the run loop; when you use a `for` loop like this, all your changes happen synchronously and the run loop never gets a chance to redraw after each change. So even if you added a delay to slow the animation down to the point where people could see it, people *still* wouldn't see it because you're not drawing it.

You can solve both problems easily using Core Animation. The example that isaac provides in his answer is fine. Without Core Animation, you'd need to use a timer to provide a delay. The timer would call your code each time it fired so that you could make your changes, and it would also allow the run loop to run normally so that the view could redraw. Core Animation makes all that much simpler -- you set the animation duration and the final values for animatable properties like `alpha`, and Core Animation takes care of adjusting the value of the property slowly over time until it reaches the final value at the end of the animation.